# Disabling boost serialization object tracking

Tags: serialization, boost

The boost serialization manual warns about problems with its own [object tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking).
I don't need that feature especially with such dangers and no benefits to my code.
Is there any way I can completely disable it for the whole project? maybe some define?

Answer (score 0):

There is a macro, but it appears to be required on a per-type basis.

Read the [Class Serialization Traits -> Object Tracking](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#tracking) section of the docs for more info.